# Unable to validate application archives of type: 0x0 in Xcode 6 when validating iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am getting the error

```
Unable to validate application archives of type: 0x0
```

when validating my application on Xcode 6. Is there a way to release the app for iOS 7 from this version of Xcode?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You cannot release apps to the App Store with XCode 6 as it is still beta and an early one at that. In the past Apple have permitted submission with new versions of XCode/iOS just prior to the final release date (ie with the final release candidate)

**UPDATE** You can now submit apps built with the Xcode 6 GM version

Comment: Should an adhoc export work for testing via testflight? Can't seem to get it to work and I wonder if this is my issue.

Comment: Buggah. I guess this is still the case for Xcode 8 beta :/ - so can't use built in test flight support?

Comment: I have built an app in Swift using Xcode 6, had the same issue. Now I try to upload it using Xcode 5, but it said: Bunde not signed using Apple Submission certificate. I have tried everything: Generated new cerfiticates, profiles etcetera, but nothing worked. How can I manage to still upload my app?

Comment: You cannot submit Swift apps at this time.  Even though you are trying to submit with Xcode 5, your app was still built and signed with Xcode 6.  You will need to wait until Apple is accepting apps built with Xcode 6

Comment: I have been using TestFlight to test my all-Swift app (https://bitbucket.org/bmlt/nacc). No problem. I just can't submit it to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

[Under known issue in xcode-beta-5](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_5_za4gu6/xcode_6_beta_5_release_notes.pdf)

**App Validation**

> • Validating archives may not work. (16891311)