# Unable to upload iPhone app using Xcode 6 beta

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

I am trying to upload a new version of my iPhone app but I am getting following error:

> unable to validate application archives of type 0x0

I can't upload it from Xcode 5 as I am getting error because of new api of push notification. My app is not using swift and has a small code change in previous version. How can I upload this new version of the app?

Comment: Xcode 6 is no longer in beta. Try using the latest version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to validate application archives of type: 0x0 in Xcode 6 when validating iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126834/unable-to-validate-application-archives-of-type-0x0-in-xcode-6-when-validating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not allow developers to upload apps using beta versions of Xcode. [Xcode 6 is now out on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12), and the GM can also be downloaded from their developer site.

> Do not submit apps built using beta software, as beta versions of Xcode, Operating Systems, and SDKs are for development and testing only.

Source: [Apple's Dev Site](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/)

Comment: yes uploaded successfully on Apple Store with Xcode 6 final version